# Map each text node to an anonymous function in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have the below variable `data` as a dictionary, presumable parsed from a JSON file:

```py
data = {
    "import": ["mod1\u1251", "mod\u2412"],
    "other \u2512fos fields": {
        "name": "2"
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to `map` each node inside of this data structure to an anonymous function?

For instance, an example would be:

```py
data = {...} # above data

"""
map_nodes would push import, mod1, mod2, other_fields, name, Jack into the anonymous string_fix function (these are our node values).

Once returned, the return is placed in the proper reference, simplifying the ability to iterate over every node or k/v in a dict or object.
"""
def string_fix(string):
    return "".join([c for c in string if ord(c) < 128]).strip()
data = map_nodes(string_fix, data)
```

This `string_fix` function is removing unicode and stripping whitespace from the string. Don't take the sample data too seriously.

Then, after mapping the `string_fix` function to each node, the data would look something like:

```py
data = {
    "import": ["mod1", "mod2"],
    "other fos fields": {
        "name": "2"
    }
}
```

This is likely possible writing my own function, I just wanted to ask if there was a grounded solution to this.

I've searched around for:

- json map each text node
- Python mapping dictionary recursively

Comment: Can you include an example of what you expect `data` to contain after `data = map_nodes(str, data)`?

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you are looking for an algorithm that takes every string it can take (key, values, list elements...) and process them in-place using the str function? If this is what you meant, could you define the prototype of the function you want to pass? Should it take a single string parameter as input and return a string as an output?

Comment: @Grismar I'll do this now, I should have used the issue I was solving primarily. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: `"mod\u2"`: this gives me an error: `"truncated \uXXXX escape"`. Could you please fix your snippet of code?

Comment: The same thing applies to `"other \u2fos fields"`. Then, would you want to convert the `2` into a string?

Comment: I've edited my answer: could you take a look at it? (And could you tell me if you receive a notification when I edit my answer, so I know if I should comment it or not?)

Comment: @lax48 unfortunately I didn't see the new answer as a notification. But, if I was in the website when the question was changed it'd say you changed it and ask me to reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answers your question

```python
# Here you have your data
data = {
    "import": ["mod1", "mod2"],
    "other_fields": {
        "name": "Jack"
    }
}

# Here you have your function: it takes one string as parameter and returns a string
def doSomething(param):
    return param.upper()

# Here there is the black magic
def map_nodes(func, data):
    # Check what type is data
    if type(data) == dict:
        ret = {}
        # In dictionaries just iterate and replace keys and values
        for k, v in data.items():
            nk = map_nodes(func, k)
            nv = map_nodes(func, v)
            ret[nk] = nv
    elif type(data) == list:
        ret = []
        # In lists just iterate and replace the value
        for v in data:
            v = map_nodes(func, v)
            ret.append(v)
    elif type(data) == str:
        ret = ""
        # In strings just replace the value
        ret = func(data)
    elif type(data) == int:
        # In integers just convert into strings
        ret = map_nodes(func, str(data))
    # Here you can add all the other types you may need
    else:
        # Raise an exception if we haven't recognized the type
        raise Exception("Type " + str(type(data)) + " is not implemented yet!")

    return ret

print(data)

data = map_nodes(doSomething, data)

print(data)
```

This outputs:

```
{'import': ['mod1', 'mod2'], 'other_fields': {'name': 'Jack'}}
{'IMPORT': ['MOD1', 'MOD2'], 'OTHER_FIELDS': {'NAME': 'JACK'}}
```

---

With the new inputs provided and tweaked a little bit in order to let Python parse, the output is:

```
{'import': ['mod1ቑ', 'mod╅'], 'other ┲fos fields': {'name': 2}}
{'import': ['mod1', 'mod'], 'other fos fields': {'name': '2'}}
```

Look at this [repl](https://repl.it/@lax48/stackoverflow66484124) to see my code in action.